# Sort multidimensional array prioritising substring

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array to work with and sort in PHP.
I am trying to sort it by the **product_code** key. The array needs to be arranged

- first in the ascending order of the **last two characters of product_code**
- then in the ascending order of the **characters preceding the '.' of product_code**

Here is the array I have

```
Array

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Stellar
            [product_code] => C5311.01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Luigi
            [product_code] => C5310.02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Apple
            [product_code] => C5310.01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Quietly
            [product_code] => C5311.02
        )
)
```

This needs to be sorted as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Apple
            [product_code] => C5310.01
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Stellar
            [product_code] => C5311.01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Luigi
            [product_code] => C5310.02
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Quietly
            [product_code] => C5311.02
        )
```

)

I thought sorting the array by **product_code** key first and then by the substring using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) would yield me favourable results, but I was wrong. Maybe I am trying too hard..

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `usort` is actually what you need, but I think you are wrong in the way you are using it. If you need to sort

> - first in the ascending order of the last two characters of product_code
> - then in the ascending order of the characters preceding the '.' of product_code

just write a function which do this and pass it to `usort`:

```
function cmp($a,$b){
      $lastTwoDigitsCmp=strcmp(substr($a["product_code"], -2), substr($b["product_code"], -2));
      if($lastTwoDigitsCmp==0)
          return strcmp($a["product_code"],$b["product_code"]);
      else
          return $lastTwoDigitsCmp;

}
```

This should do the job.